# Remove click behaviour from md-list-item (AngularJS Material)

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, material-design

In AngularJS Material, I want a simple list, not clickable items, just text with the correct spacing. I cannot make a non-clickable list!

I have looked over the documentation and I don't understand why  is always adding class="md-clickable"... here is my code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaJpGY

```
<md-content class="acc-content">


          <md-list>
              <md-list-item>
                <md-checkbox ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="true"></md-checkbox>
                <p class="md-list-item-text">Agree to terms and conditions</p>
              </md-list-item>
              <md-list-item>
                <md-checkbox></md-checkbox><p>Provide personal details</p>
              </md-list-item>
              <md-list-item>
                <md-checkbox></md-checkbox><p>Bank details</p>
              </md-list-item>
          </md-list>


    </md-content>
```

How do I make these list items non-clickable?

Comment: You can easily disabled checkbox with: [disabled]="boolean"

Comment: Why don't you just remove `<mg-checkbox>` tags. If the user can't click on them, it's useless to keep them.

Comment: i want the checkboxes. If you look at my code you will see some are disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to disable your `list-item`.

```
<md-content class="acc-content">
      <md-list>
          <md-list-item ng-disabled="true"> <!-- here -->
            <md-checkbox ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="true"></md-checkbox>
            <p class="md-list-item-text">Agree to terms and conditions</p>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-checkbox></md-checkbox><p>Provide personal details</p>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-checkbox></md-checkbox><p>Bank details</p>
          </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
</md-content>
```

Comment: yes that works perfectly! It hadn't occured to me to try that

Comment: + I'll add an extra CSS class to disable the mouse pointer on hover, then its perfect :)

Comment: Regrettably requires additional watchers.

Comment: Does it really require a watcher, since it takes a non-interpolated value?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `class="md-no-proxy"` to your `md-list-item` tag

See https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdListItem

```
<md-content class="acc-content">
      <md-list>
          <md-list-item class="md-no-proxy"> <!-- here -->
            <md-checkbox ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="true"></md-checkbox>
            <p class="md-list-item-text">Agree to terms and conditions</p>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-checkbox></md-checkbox><p>Provide personal details</p>
          </md-list-item>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-checkbox></md-checkbox><p>Bank details</p>
          </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
</md-content>
```